# Can m.2 form factors be converted?

Tags: m.2

I recently bought an Intel 8260 wireless network card marked m.2. I have a NUC with an m.2 slot.  I expected plug and play.  And I quickly found out the m.2 form factor is fairly rich.

In this case, the card is actually an m.2 2230 keyed A+E.  The NUC accepts m.2 2242, 2260, and 2280 cards all keyed to M.

Is there a way to get this m.2 2230 A+E to fit into a m.2 2242/2260/2280 M?

Is there a relationship between the physical dimensions WWLL (eg 2242, 2260, etc) and the key?

Network cards are also commonly packaged with mini PCIe connectors.  Can I somehow fit a mini PCIe network card to an m.2 2242/2260/2280 slot?

I'm guessing someone will point out that all the NUC varieties already have either m.2 A+E slots or soldered wifi cards.  I am trying to connect two wireless interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get this m.2 2230 A+E to fit into a m.2 2242/2260/2280 M?

For practical reasons: No.
(I guess a hammer could serve, but then it would no longer work)

> Is there a relationship between the physical dimensions WWLL (eg 2242, 2260, etc) and the key?

No, there is not. The WW and LL indications just indicate the physical size of the card. As you probably already found, the first two digits are for the width, which can be 12, 16, **22** and 30 mm. And the second pair of digits is for the length: (16, 26, 30, 38, **42**, 60, 80, 110mm).

As long as there is physically room on the motherboard and as long as you can securely mount it the physical size does not matter. What is important is the key, which indicates which lines are connected to the M.2 socket.

The relevant keys here are:

- Key A: The card can do PCIe ×2, USB 2.0, I2C and DP ×4.
- Key E: The card can do PCIe ×2, USB 2.0, I2C, SDIO, UART and PCM.
- Key M: The socket offers PCIe ×4, SATA and SMBus.

Your card is an M.2 2230 A+E, that means it can do PCI-e or USB. The connector only supplies PCI-e.

Since both the card and the socket offer PCI-e it should technically be possible to connect is somehow. However the price of such an adaptor is likely to exceed that of a of the 8260 card, and mounting it safely might also be tricky.

Regular PCI-e to M.2 'convertor plugin cards` are common though. How many PCI-e slots do you have left in your NUC?